# $this->params returns null in cakephp model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model, cakephp-2.4

I decided to add some extra data about the controllers and actions in some model beforeSave as follows:

```
//in the model
public function beforeSave() {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['path'] = 'blah blan';
        debug($this->params);
        die(); //for debugging!
}
```

The printout of debug returns **null**! The model I uses is the Comment model of the comments plugin. I need to access params to get the current controller, actions and some url parameters.

*Indeed, I plan to change the way that comments plugin lists the comments from model based to be path based to solve the issue of need comments for more than one action depend on the same model.*

Comment: It might be a case of not being able to use `$this->data` in the `beforeSave` callback. Have you tried to use it in another part of the model (or in the controller/view) to see if your data makes it there?

Comment: @scrowler Yes it works in the controller and returns an array.

Comment: If it works in the controller then what's the problem?

Comment: I need it to work from the model.

Comment: set a model variable - `var $path;` then in `beforeSave` add `$this->path = 'blah blan';` - and use that from within your model, use `$this->params` from outside it

Comment: I believe you're looking for $this->request->params, not $this->params - though - not sure if it will work in the model

Comment: @Dave `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Yah - didn't figure it'd work in the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution: It is in `Router` object method `getParams()`;

```
//in the model
public function beforeSave() {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['path'] = 'blah blan';
        debug(Router::getParams());
        die(); //for debugging!
}
```

it prints out something like:

```
array(
    'plugin' => null,
    'controller' => 'qurans',
    'action' => 'view',
    'named' => array(
        'comment' => '0'
    ),
    'pass' => array(
        (int) 0 => '8'
    )
)
```