# CakePHP: Securely setting a default value on a form

Tags: php, security, cakephp

In CakePHP 2.4, how does one securely set part of a form to a default value?

On my user registration view, I'm currently setting the default group_id to `3` with this- but it seems like it would be a huge security hole to do it in the view, should anyone forge a form.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden('group_id', array('value'=>'3')); ?>
```

My current `register` method:

```
public function register() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'), 'flash/success');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash/error');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Cant you set the default value in your register function? Something like $this->request->data['group_id'] = 3 instead of doing it in the view

Comment: I tried putting that right under `if ($this->request->is('post')) {` but it just leaves the field blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the value in the form but before you save the data. Only set values in hidden fields if it is required to be done in the view layer, if not always set such values in the controller, better model. Remember: Fat models, skinny controllers.

You should *always* use the Security component in your projects to avoid form tampering and other attacks.

Have a read about the security component here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#form-tampering-prevention

> By default SecurityComponent prevents users from tampering with forms.
>   It does this by working with FormHelper and tracking which files are
>   in a form. It also keeps track of the values of hidden input elements.
>   All of this data is combined and turned into a hash. When a form is
>   submitted, SecurityComponent will use the POST data to build the same
>   structure and compare the hash.

Add this component to your add model.

You can save the value in [beforeSave()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Model.html#3614-3625) as well, you just need to check if the record is going to be a new one or if it already exists by checking if the id is present.

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (empty($this->id) && empty($this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['group_id'] = 3;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Usually the id is only present when the record exists, if you want to make it more solid you can check exists() for that id as well to be totally sure it's not already there.

Another best practice hint:

```
$this->data[$this->alias]['group_id'] = 3;
```

Sucks. Nobody ever knows what 3 is. If the groups are not changing it is better to have an empty, tableless model or a simple class with constants:

```
$this->data[$this->alias]['group_id'] = UserGroup::USER;
$this->data[$this->alias]['group_id'] = UserGroup::ADMIN;
$this->data[$this->alias]['group_id'] = // You get the idea...
```

If the groups are dynamic for some reason I guess they still have some kind of identifier:

```
$this->data[$this->alias]['group_id'] = $this->UserGroup->getDefaultGroupId();
```

Comment: Oh, it all sounds so silly. The authors must be know nothing about security. If you don't want something to be forged - don't put it in the form. It's *that easy*.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in your `User` model. There is a model's callback called `beforeSave` you can use it to add the `group_id` value. **Don't do it from the view**.

```
//in User.php

public function beforeSave(){
   $this->data['User']['group_id'] = 3;
}
```

See more [in the official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave).

**Edited:**

To know the current action we will use the Router object according to the following question's answer: [$this->params returns null in cakephp model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351515/this-params-returns-null-in-cakephp-model)

So, we may modify the previous code to be:

```
//in User.php

public function beforeSave(){
   $params = Router::getParams();
   if ($params['action'] == 'register'){ 
       $this->data['User']['group_id'] = 3;
      }
}
```

Comment: How do you restrict this callback to certain methods, so editing users doesn't automatically set group_id to 3 every time? The `beforeSave` documentation doesn't mention this.

Comment: Downvoted because of introducing tight coupling with a static call and the model should not need to be aware of the Router. If you want to go this route, then the proper check would be if $this->id or if the id is present in the data to know if a record is about to be created or if it's edited. Also you're missing the $options argument in the beforeSave() which causes strict errors on php 5.4+ and up to date CakePHP. Further you couple the model code with a specific controller action and don't even check the controller as well. If the params are needed they should be passed to the model.

Comment: Could not fit everything into one comment: $this->data['User'] is another game breaker. The code wont work if the model is used through an association with a different alias than the original name. You also don't return boolean, should be there in a proper example. Pretty much bad practice in just a few lines.

Comment: @burzum `The code wont work if the model is used through an association with a different` This is conditional objection and it is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @sємsєм this doesn't make it right and I think examples should be provided in the best possible and correct way so that people learn to do things right and best practice. So that he didn't ask for it doesn't justify to not do it right IMHO.