# Passing non-form data before save (CakePHP)

Tags: php, cakephp

Course HasMany Lesson.

I am trying to save a lesson in a Course view, but want to automatically assign the current course_id without them having to select it.

How do I do that?

Here is my Courses view controller:

```
public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Course->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid course'));
        }
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Course.' . $this->Course->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->set('course', $this->Course->find('first', $options));

        //Adding Lesson from Course View
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {


            $this->Course->Lesson->create();

            if ($this->Course->Lesson->save($this->request->data)) {

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The lesson has been saved.'), array ('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
                return $this->redirect(array('controller'=> 'lessons', 'action' => 'view', $this->Course->Lesson->id));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The lesson could not be saved. Please, try again.'), array ('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
            }
        }
        $courses = $this->Course->Lesson->Course->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('courses'));


    }
```

Currently, it's saving the lesson but not passing the course_id to the new lesson.

Lesson Model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Course' => array(
            'className' => 'Course',
            'foreignKey' => 'course_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

Course Model:

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Lesson' => array(
            'className' => 'Lesson',
            'foreignKey' => 'course_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
```

Comment: Can you share a debug print out of `$this->request->data` and can you edit to show the Lesson and Course Models?

Comment: just assign a value to `$this->request->data`. You are not showing your view so we don't know if you've set it as a hidden value... Have you tried searching around? this looks like a simple [blog tutorial post](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#editing-posts) problem...

Comment: @Nunser I knew that's what I have to do I am just mangling the syntax. Can you help?

Comment: @enigmasck Updated with the models.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP: Securely setting a default value on a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866117/cakephp-securely-setting-a-default-value-on-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a duplicate of [CakePHP: Securely setting a default value on a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866117/cakephp-securely-setting-a-default-value-on-a-form/21866495).

Check my answer there or read [the blog article I've wrote after that answer](http://florian-kraemer.net/2014/02/best-practice-for-dealing-with-additional-data-in-beforesave/).

Comment: Thanks Burzum - this is almost the answer. Except I'm not confused on how to save the data - rather I'm confused about two things:
1) Whether to put the beforesave in Lesson (record created) or Course (view the form is on) models.

2) The exact syntax.